# How can I rescale the range of variables in a 2D plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

In python matplotlib, I would like to make a 2D color-plot of a function `z`  in terms of two variables `x` and `y`. The range of parameter `x` is much smaller than parameter `y` such that it is almost invisible which is which when I plot. I would like to keep the number of steps in each of `x` and `y` the same. How can I rescale the range of `x`? Following is part of my code in which I plot.

```
x1,y1,z1 = np.loadtxt("TDFD_Effectualness_etta_%s_%s.dat" % (waveform2, waveform1)).T #Transposed for easier unpacking

nrows, ncols = final_step_j-1, final_step_k-1
grid1 = z1.reshape((nrows, ncols))

plt.xlabel('eta')
plt.ylabel('M_chirp')

plt.imshow(grid1, extent=(x1.min(), x1.max(), y1.min(), y1.max()), origin='lower', vmin=-5, vmax=5, 
        interpolation='nearest', 
        cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.suptitle('Effectualness_etta of %s and %s' % (waveform1, waveform2))
plt.colorbar()
plt.draw()
fig1.savefig('/home/saeed/pycbc/test/plots/New_Effectualness_etta_%s_%s.pdf' % (waveform1, waveform2), dpi=100)

plt.imshow(grid2, extent=(x2.min(), x2.max(), y2.min(), y2.max()), origin='lower', vmin=-5, vmax=5, 
        interpolation='nearest', 
        cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)

close('all')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to change the aspect ratio of the image. This can be done using the `aspect` keyword of `imshow`:

```
plt.imshow(grid1,
    extent=(x1.min(), x1.max(), y1.min(), y1.max()),
    origin='lower', vmin=-5, vmax=5, aspect='auto',
    interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! `aspect='auto'` is indeed a better choice.